# Canvas in contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, contenteditable

```css
.editor {
         width: 100%;
         min-height: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background-color: black;
         color: #fff;
        }
 canvas {
            background-color: green;
        }
```

```html
<div class="editor" contenteditable><canvas></canvas></div>
```

How could I add canvas to contenteditable div

I have this code

```
<style>
.editor {
         width: 100%;
         min-height: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background-color: black;
         color: #fff;
        }
 canvas {
            background-color: green;
        }
</style>


<div class="editor" contenteditable><canvas></canvas></div>
```

For some reason I'm not able to write anything into the contenteditable div and even the caret somehow disappear. What I'm doing wrong? A help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Your code correctly renders a green canvas inside a div element and such div as being contenteditable takes input focus and gives the opportunity to type text inside shifting the canvas among the new text content. You can't give focus to the div? not at all?

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug, works fine in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: That would be https://crbug.com/242110

Answer (score 0):

```css
.editor {
         width: 100%;
         min-height: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background-color: black;
         color: #fff;
         position:relative;
        }
canvas {
            background-color: green;     color: #fff;
        }
```

```html
<div class="editor" contenteditable>
  <canvas></canvas>
&nbsp;
<p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

`contenteditable` is saying that the **div's content** is editable, not the div itself, so use a p in the div to be your textbox or put a placeholder in, otherwise the content that you will be editing is the canvas. As other answers point out this is a Chrome bug, if you want to simulate the behaviour as other browsers, you can add a space in the div like this, otherwise the p solution still works.

Comment: it's not different than just making the div contenteditable. The OP said he couldn't type text inside while actually its code already worked like that. The question remains unclear

Comment: I tested it on Firefox and it's working on it but not on chrome.

Comment: well I was using chrome so that explains it, my code works on all browsers

Answer (score 0):

With a little Javascript you can sort of cheat it by adding a blank space and then forcing the caret to be placed at the end of the content

```js
document.querySelector('.editor').onclick=e=>{
  if( e.target==e.currentTarget ){
    const setcaret=(n)=>{
      let oSel=window.getSelection();
          oSel.selectAllChildren( n );
          oSel.collapseToEnd();
    }
    
    e.target.innerHTML += '&nbsp;';
    setcaret( e.target );
  }
};
```

```css
.editor {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding:1rem;
}

canvas {
  background-color: green;
  width:100px;height:100px;margin:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contenteditable>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Would need the same trick to set the caret before.